# VBA para salvar em PDF a planilha do Excel com o nome de duas Células

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

A planilha que faço salva em pdf com esse código:

```
Sub Salvar_PDF()

'Antes de executar o código é importante definir a áreade impressão

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\c098150\HUDSON\GEGRO\FORMS\Customização N.º .pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Quero acrescentar o número que tá na celula S7 e o nome que tá na D13

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que eu entendi, você quer que os valores nas células S7 e D13 estejam presentes no nome do PDF a ser criado.

Para isso, é só concatenar, usando o  "&", a instrução "Range('Endereço da célula').value" no código, desse jeito:

```
Sub Salvar_PDF()

'Antes de executar o código é importante definir a áreade impressão

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\Users\c098150\HUDSON\GEGRO\FORMS\Customização " & Range("S7").Value & " N.º " & Range("D13").Value & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```